# How does method reference casting work?

Tags: java, casting, lambda, java-8, method-reference

```
public class Main {
    interface Capitalizer {
        public String capitalize(String name);
    }

    public String toUpperCase() {
        return "ALLCAPS";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Capitalizer c = String::toUpperCase; //This works
        c = Main::toUpperCase; //Compile error
    }
}
```

Both are instance methods with same signature. Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Signature of `String::toUpperCase`: `String toUpperCase();`

Comment: Specify "does not work". Is there a compile time error, runtime exception? And why do you think that adding an inner interface to Main adds a method "capitalize" to Main?

Comment: Can you include the method `String capitalize(String)` in `Main`  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 constructs to reference a method:

1. `object::instanceMethod`
2. `Class::staticMethod`
3. `Class::instanceMethod`

The line:

```
Capitalizer c = String::toUpperCase; //This works
```

use 3'rd construct - `Class::instanceMethod`. In this case **first parameter becomes the target of the method**. This construct is equivalent (translates) to following Lambda:

```
Capitalizer = (String x) -> x.toUpperCase();
```

This Lambda expression works because Lambda **gets `String` as parameter and returns `String` result - as required by `Capitalizer` interface**.

The line:

```
c = Main::toUpperCase; //Compile error
```

Translates to:

```
(Main m) ->  m.toUpperCase();
```

Which does not work with the `Capitalizer` interface. You could verify this by changing `Capitalizer` to:

```
interface Capitalizer {
    public String capitalize(Main name);
}
```

After this change `Main::toUpperCase` will compile.

Comment: there is the fourth kind of method references: `ClassName::new` (reference to a constructor)

Comment: and another form of method reference is: `String.class::cast` which can be `stringClass::cast` where `Class<String> stringClass = String.class`

Answer (score 4):

You have a method which

```
public String capitalize(String name);
```

Takes a `String` and returns a `String`.  Such a method can have a number of patterns.

A constructor

```
c = String::new; // calls new String(String)
// or
c = s -> new String(s);
```

A function on `String` which takes no arguments

```
c = String::toLowerCase; // instance method String::toLowerCase()
// or
c = s -> s.toLowerCase();
```

of a method which takes a String as the only argument

```
// method which takes a String, but not a Main
public static String toUpperCase(String str) { 

c = Main::toUpperCase;
// or
c = s -> toUpperCase(s);
```

In every case, the method referenced has to take the String.

If not you can do this instead.

```
c = s -> capitalize(); // assuming Main.capitalize() is static
```

This tells the compiler to ignore the input.

Comment: I'm not getting this. `the method referenced has to take the String` why does `String::toUpperCase` work? It doesn't take any String.

Comment: I'm also not getting this.

Comment: @KshitizSharma Instance / non-static methods need an instance.

Comment: @Yoooo Instance / non-static methods need an instance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You mean when I use String::toUpper the compiler sees that String::toUpper is an instance method and therefore implicitly takes the first and only parameter as instance on which it can operate ?

Comment: @Yoooo Yes, `String::toLowerCase;` is almost the same as `s -> s.toLowerCase();` with subtle differences.

Comment: So what's exactly the differences? Except that the writing is not the same 

Comment: @Yoooo a method reference is entirely metadata in the class. The lambda is implemented using a generated static method that in turn is called as a method reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
public String toUpperCase()
```

to

```
public static String toUpperCase(String text)
```

---

You should read the java tutorial on [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The different kind of method references and there is a similar example with `String::compareToIgnoreCase` (Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type).

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference String::compareToIgnoreCase would have the formal parameter list (String a, String b), where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method a.compareToIgnoreCase(b).

Comment: because String class toUpperCase method has the same signature as the capitalize method.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov No it doesn't.